# How can I best debug solr in intelliJ-idea?

Tags: java, debugging, solr, intellij-idea

How can I best debuging solr in intelliJ-idea? Which way is easy? when post a query to solr, I want to handle this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set up the remote debugging. In the **Run/Debug Configurations**:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA remote debugging]

Then when starting your solr with the default jetty (this one is in multicore mode), pass in:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -Dsolr.solr.home=multicore -jar start.jar
```

After solr has started hit **Run -> Debug** button and choose the **debug** config. The IntelliJ IDEA attaches to the Solr java process and all the debugging goodies should be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run SOLR with command

```
solr -f -a "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=4044"
```

2. This run configuration:
   [image]