# Intellij & Solr8 : How to setup a project?

Tags: intellij-idea, run-configuration, solr8

I need help with Run/Debug Configurations for my Solr8 project. From terminal I use command "bin/solr start" But then I can not debug my transformers. For this I need to add Run Config in Intellij. Any help is Appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: You can create a shell script run configuration. For debugging see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23542336/104891.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answers helped me to come up with this solution. I added Run Config as below. First I started Solr from command line with /opt/solr/bin/solr start  -a "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
And then From Intellij, selected the run config I added and clicked on debug

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SOLR start-p 8988-f-a "-xdebug-xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y, suspend=y,address=8988
```